# Network Diagram Duration Problem in time management

Tags: time-management

I am practicing exam nowadays to get PMP exam using famous exam simulator but i found question i cannot determine how they draw the diagram table below :

[image]

& they draw it like the following :

[image]

my question is how the ***End*** have 2 duration & how i can calculate critical path??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like the estimate is some floating time? Otherwise I don't understand why a task should have two durations either... Is there any additional description?

Answer (score 1):

Critical path follows the longest duration path, which is `Start->Task 3->Task 5->End`.

`End` appears twice in the table since it follows each of Tasks 2 and 5, which are independent branches. `End` appears only once in the graph, as the terminal state, as you would expect.